# Django: How can I implement a low level login using a md5 password column since I'm porting over my users table from an old site?

Tags: django, django-authentication

Basically, I currently have `login/` in `urls.py` redirect to the `django.contrib.auth.views.login` and that seems to work out fine.

However I'm porting over passwords from a legacy mysql/php site and I believe I should just create a new model profile per http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users. This new model/table will have the old md5 password column, and I'll port over the usernames to the main users table.

How could I change the login method such that I first check if the user has a password in the `auth_user` table, and if not then md5 the POST `password` field and attempt to match it to my new profile password column, if so save the password in the new `auth_user` table by SHA1 encrypting like how the admin does it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would create a new view that does something along the following:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, check_password
import hashlib

def login_with_lookup(request):
    if request.POST: # If you want to restrict to POST
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = User.objects.get(username=username)
        profile = user.get_profile()
        if profile.old_password != '' and profile.old_password == hashlib.md5(password).hexdigest():
            user.set_password(password)
            profile.old_password = ''
            user.save() # Might need to save profile as well, not sure how it works
        if check_password(password, user.password):
            login(request, user)
    #Whatever else you want to do, followed by a render to template or redirect
```

This is un-tested, so it will need a bit of clean-up.  It will also need error checking at different points to handle failure cases (this example assumes success).

Answer (score 2):

Write a custom authentication backend:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/auth/#writing-an-authentication-backend